# Error during import csv file into PgAdmin table

Tags: database, postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

When I'm trying to import csv file's table into PgAdmin, it's being error.

> ERROR:  could not open file "D:\book.csv" for reading: No such file or
> directory
>
> HINT:  COPY FROM instructs the PostgreSQL server process to read a
> file. You may want a client-side facility such as psql's \copy.
>
> SQL state: 58P01

Comment: The error tells you the problem. The Postgres server user needs access to the file to run `COPY`. Are you using the pgAdmin [Import/Export](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/5.7/import_export_data.html) dialog?

Comment: Yes, I'm using import in pgAdmin. And it says this error